# Windows IoT Application to detect other applications running

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iot

I am trying to create an application for windows IoT that I call "KeepAlive" the function with this application is to detect if my main application called "Mekalink" is running, if the application is not running "KeepAlive" should start "Mekalink". Also the "KeepAlive" application have to job, making sure that "Mekalink" always can start, means if there are any settings that makes the program crash, it should reinstall the program.

All this i got to work on with Windows 10 and Linux, and now trying to create the same for Windows IoT, but I got a problem, I do not know how to detect which applications are running on the OS, and I as well do not know how I can start another application from my application.

I am using the background core template project downloaded here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.micros ... 2624202d36

I hope that someone here can give me information about how to detect what applications are running, something like "System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()" in the .Net framework.

And how to start another application like "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()" in the .Net framework.

Remember, all code supplied needs to target the .Net Core framework.

//NoxiaZ

Answer (score 0):

NoxiaZ,

You may see the current running applications and processes by running '[tlist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558901(v=vs.85).aspx)' from the command prompt of your device running Windows IoT Core.  This can be executed over telnet or powershell.  Similarly, you may be able to launch an application from either of these protocols.  With an open telnet session, you may simply type the directory/name of the application you wish to start.  See this [article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell), for information on running executables from Powershell.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this do not answer my question. I am not looking for command prompt, i need to do it from the code.

But actually you have me a good idea, if i dont find any other way to do it, i could from the program telnet to localhost and start the program from there and check if its running. - But i think there should be other ways around then make a telnet client.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need extra stuff for this, IoT itself already doing this if you set your program as startup from Windows Device Portal windows will keep it alive, there is only one limitation you can just have one foreground app at the same time.